# My question was deleted from StackOverflow. I'd like to repost it on Programmers.SE

Tags: discussion, support, deleted-questions

A [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10115741/the-design-of-the-net-module-system-in-comparison-to-other-common-systems#comment12962993_10115741) I posted to stack overflow was deleted a while back. I think it might be more appropriate on Programmers.StackExchange. Unfortunately, I can't see the original question and it was somewhat lengthy. Is there a way for me to get the text so that I can repost it easily? Or can someone who has access send me the text of my own question?

Comment: update - question [(re)posted on Programmers.SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/149056/the-design-of-the-net-module-system-in-comparison-to-other-common-systems)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go.

> **The design of the .NET module system (in comparison to other common systems)**
>
> In implementations of the Scheme programming language (R6RS standard)
>   I can import a module as follows:
>
> ```
> (import (abc def xyz))
> ```
>
> The system will try to look for a file `$DIR/abc/def/xyz.sls` where
>   `$DIR` is some directory where you keep your Scheme modules. `xyz.sls`
>   is the source code for the module and it is compiled on the fly if
>   necessary.
>
> The Ruby, Python, and Perl module systems are similar in this respect.
>
> C# on the other hand is a little more involved.
>
> First, you have dll files that you must reference on a per project
>   basis. You must reference each one explicitly. This is more involved
>   than say, dropping dll files in a directory and having C# pick them up
>   by name.
>
> Second, There isn't a one-to-one naming correspondence between the dll
>   filename, and the namespaces offered by the dll. I can appreciate this
>   flexibility, but it can also get out of hand (and has).
>
> It seems like the Ruby, Python, Perl, Scheme way of handling modules
>   would have been more elegant. Is there a strong reason that the
>   .NET/C# world does things in this way? It seems that emerging
>   languages tend to go with the simpler design.
>
> To make this concrete, it would be nice if, when I say this `using
>   abc.def.xyz;`, C# would try to find a file `abc/def/xyz.dll`, in some
>   directory that C# knows to look in (configurable on a per project
>   basis).

Interesting question. I hope you get a good answer.

Comment: Thanks Michael! Reposted to Programmers.

Comment: Sadly, it's already received a vote to be closed over there too...

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/149056/the-design-of-the-net-module-system-in-comparison-to-other-common-systems#comment282355_149056

Comment: And it's been closed...

Comment: Sorry to hear that, @dharmatech. Seems like a decent question. Hopefully with Gilles' clarifying edit, it'll get reopened.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta it did